# Sum of corresponding nested list elements in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a nested list like this:

```
foo <- list(
      a = list("a1" = c(1,2,3), "a2" = c(4,5,6), "a3" = c(7,8,9)),
      b = list("b1" = c(10, 20, 30), "b2" = c(40, 50, 60), "b3" = c(70, 80, 90)),
      ...
      ...
      ...
    )
```

I want to compute the sum of corresponding nested list elements:
i.e a1+b1+..., a2+b2+..., a3+b3+...
If there are just two nested list elements, a and b, they can be done like this

```
 mapply(function(x,y) x+y,  foo[[1]], foo[[2]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

But if there is a variable number of nested list elements like a, b, c, d, .. etc. I would like to write a generic script that can do this

Comment: `Reduce(\(x,y)Map('+', x, y), foo)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```r
l = min(lengths(foo))
lapply(seq(l), \(x) Reduce(`+`, unlist(lapply(foo, `[`, x), recursive = FALSE)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 11 22 33
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 44 55 66
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 77 88 99
```

Or, if you want the sum in each:

```r
sapply(1:3, \(x) Reduce(`+`, unlist(lapply(foo, `[`, x))))
#[1]  66 165 264
```

Comment: `Reduce(\(x,y)Map('+', x, y), foo)`

Comment: Thanks! In your code:
l = min(lengths(foo))
lapply(seq(l), \(x) Reduce(`+`, unlist(lapply(foo, `[`, x), recursive = FALSE)))
Can the `+` be replaced by a function? Like instead of sum, I want 1- (x/y)
So the results will be 
1-(1/10)
1-(2/20)
1-(3/30)
...

Comment: @Onyambu your answer is the most concise and works for 2+ list elements, I'd go for adding it as an answer

Comment: @ACE Yes, you can do it with anonymous functions: instead `+`, add `function(x, y) 1 - (x/y)`. Note that this of course only works when you have two nested list elements

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Reduce` + `Map` + `list2DF` like below

```
> unname(as.list(Reduce(`+`, Map(list2DF, foo))))
[[1]]
[1] 11 22 33

[[2]]
[1] 44 55 66

[[3]]
[1] 77 88 99
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do

```
do.call(Map, c(f = `+`, foo))
```

-output

```
$a1
[1] 11 22 33

$a2
[1] 44 55 66

$a3
[1] 77 88 99
```

---

Or with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(foo, reduce, `+`)
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working for more than two nested list elements. Try with `foo <- list(a = list(a1 = c(1, 2, 3), a2 = c(4, 5, 6), a3 = c(7, 8, 9)),
     b = list(b1 = c(10, 20, 30), b2 = c(40, 50, 60), b3 = c(70, 80, 90)), 
     c = list(c1 = c(1, 2, 3), c2 = c(4, 5, 6), c3 = c(7, 8, 9)))
`